# Amazon SP-API feeds API POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA Failing To Update Price

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral, amazon-selling-partner-api

I tried using the Amazon Feeds API to upload a feed and was successful in updating the quantity.

But what about the price?  It failed.

Here is the xml I uploaded:

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <AmazonEnvelope>
            <Header>
              <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
              <MerchantIdentifier>XXXXXXXXXXXX</MerchantIdentifier>
            </Header>
            <MessageType>Price</MessageType>
            <Message>
              <MessageID>1</MessageID>
              <Price>
                <SKU>XXXXXXXXXXX</SKU>
                <StandardPrice currency="USD">100.00</StandardPrice>
              </Price>
            </Message>
          </AmazonEnvelope>
```

After waiting, the price remained the same.

How can I update the price? Is the above XML not correct to make the price change?

Please can you show me an example that will update the price via the feed API?

Comment: Did you find any answer?

Comment: It appears there is a solution here: https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/issues/2167  I have yet to test but others are confirming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Message node needs to specify operation type.

```
 <Message> 
      <MessageID>1</MessageID>
      <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
      <Price>                 
            <SKU>1234567</SKU>
            <StandardPrice currency="USD">100.00</StandardPrice>
       </Price>
     </Message>

  Other possible values are Delete and PartialUpdate
```